BIG Query recursive CTE or other possible solution
I have a table with 10 million unique Product_ID. This Unique Ids are being tested by the hr and the metric has a [good : -1, neutral : 0, bad : 1], I call this column hr_status. I want to develop a workflow that looks into the recursive sum of these integers and makes a desicion on designing the product for inspection or not.
The logic is as follows
TOP SUM:
if the cumulative sum of these hr status gets to be 5, then sets it for inspection, BUT do not go over 5, meaning 5 is out top and if more signals come with (bad:1) I will not continue adding, instead leave the recursive sum on 45
BOTTOM:
for the case that many good singals in a row happend I do not want to go below 0, so 0 will be out bottom lowest value for the SUM.
Sample Table:



Product_ID
time
hr_status




AA
6/10/2024  01:10:10 AM
-1


AA
6/10/2024  02:10:10 AM
0


AA
6/10/2024  03:10:10 AM
1


AA
6/10/2024  04:10:10 AM
1


AA
6/10/2024  05:10:10 AM
1


AA
6/10/2024  06:10:10 AM
1


AA
6/10/2024  07:10:10 AM
1


AA
6/10/2024  08:10:10 AM
1


AA
6/10/2024  09:10:10 AM
1



My Expected CUM_SUM column for the above example should look like this [assuming we starting from 0]



CUM_SUM




0


0


1


2


3


4


5


5


5



Previous attempt was a POC but it was just in python with for loops inside for loops and that wont work for big data.
I want want to slve this in BigQuery but it also exists the posibility of using pyspark.
So far I have tried a combination of row_number() over partition but have not been sucessful. I wonder if SQL recursive is an option that it is worth exploring.

Do you want to look back only over a specific timeframe? e.g. in the previous 24 hours or  7 days (or previous 168 hours, working back from the most recent time value). Does it add value to look back over a Product_ID's test result (hr_status) over all time? I am thinking to just create a subset of the data for the timespan required. Also to improve runtime and reduce costs, I would suggest having a partition of the time field.
